# Choosing a Game Engine for my 2D Game

Tags: 2d, game-engine

I am starter game developer. And also i am 2nd year student of software engineering. I have a team, and i am the only 1 who can code something!(And i have a guy from Marvel :))) )

So, we have decided to do a 2D game targeted to PC. I have made research in this side. And found not so many choices, because at the moment 3D games are in fashion. I do not want to use a game maker by the way.

So i decided to ask you this questions:Can you give some advise about using an engine or i have to write my own one? And if i have to write my own engine, which resources must i have?

Appreciate each of your answer !

Thanx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you should start by researching what a typical game engine gives you.  There's a lot usually, such as physics, wrappers to draw objects, wrappers to load assests (such as sound and models or pictures), possibly even networking.

A game engine is potentially a huge, huge undertaking. If you're looking to make a game, focus on that by utilizing what's available to you.

My suggestion for starting would be XNA.  It's a quick learn for the basics and easy to scale for large projects.  They provide a lot of what I talked about and allows you to focus on what you started the project for.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

Since PC games has many awesome titles out there, I think indie developer like you should heading for simple and time-killer games for mobile, a good game engine for mobile (free version available) is Gideros Mobile (http://www.giderosmobile.com). It use Lua language and you can publish for both Android and iOS platform. Gideros also has an active community which are ready to answer all your questions at here: http://www.giderosmobile.com/forum/

Currently I have 6 month experience with it, publish 3 games with about 60.000+ downloads.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a lower-level language like C++, I suggest SFML.  It is extremely simple to use and provides both high-level and low-level graphics, audio, and networking functions for different uses.
You can also use it to easily create a context for OpenGL.

http://www.sfml-dev.org/

You will have to build the latest and best version (2.0) yourself, but this tutorial will show you how:

http://sfmlcoder.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/building-sfml-2-0-with-mingw-make/

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest checking out FlashPunk or Flixel. Both are Flash-based engines, so they use Actionscript 3, and can target the web-browser (Flash), or PC/Mac via the use of Adobe Air. Also, the performance isn't quite there yet from what I have read, but Adobe Air can also deploy to both iOS and Android. This is merely just a suggestion though, and if I were you I'd test out a few engines/technologies until finding the one I am most comfortable with.

Good luck!

Links to both:
http://www.flashpunk.net
http://flixel.org